# Reversible showers, should they be avoided?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I purchased this shower kit from Costco:

https://www.costco.ca/ove-nicole-42-in.-corner-shower-enclosure-with-base.product.100980337.html?preselect=colour%3achrome

It looks like it's reversible, meaning there are no integrated flanges (built into the base) and you have to install them with silicone to prevent leaks. Here I'm talking about the shower base tiling flange which has to be screwed into the base and the studs and sealed with silicone.

Should I shop for something else with integrated flanges?

Comment: Also, questions in this forum need to be more specific ... don't say "Should I".  Please change that.  I will assume the goal is to prevent leaks.

Comment: It really depends on the details. A couple of necessary conditions come to mind. Is the flange very stiff and/or does it use a lot of fasteners? Is it constructed such that there are no positions where resting water could accumulate? Even satisfying these two conditions, I'm still weary. I would want to toy with the thing.

Comment: Interesting, the Costco listing says a base is included, [the manual](https://www.ovedecors.com/pub/media/amasty/amfile/attach/IM_Nicole.pdf) shows pictures of the stall in two different configurations, on page 3 it shows a base *with a flange* that can't be reversible,  and does not mention the base anywhere else, or how to install it.  Very odd.  Does the manual you got in the box look exactly like the one I linked to?

Comment: The manual also has a broken link to a youtube installation video.  But if you look around you can find it.  I see now, the manual in my above link pictures an integrated flange but they also have the same base with a glue-on flange.  I'm not linking to the video because you can't unsee it, and you'll have nightmares.  I don't know how you would seal the corner of this thing properly.

Comment: This is a shopping advice question and should be closed.

Comment: @jay613 I looked at other companies and it does look like this design is more and more common. Maybe people screwed up orders too often so they make it reversible now. I'm guessing good silicone shielded with other layers will last 20+ years.

Comment: @FreeMan This is not a shopping advice question. This question is about the reliability of reversible shower base designs (screw on flanges). Read beyond the fact that the question includes the word "shop".

Comment: Then maybe you should edit the question to ask "how should I seal this?" or "is this reliable?" or something other than "should I shop for a different one?"

Comment: @FreeMan I think sometimes we can apply a generous interpretation to a question (even if there is room for improvement), and in this case it would be "Can a pan with a detachable flange be as reliable as one with an integrated flange  if suitable installation and maintenance is followed in either case, and if so, what tips and tricks should I follow?".   I don't think we have to force every new OP to eloquently spell out the question in a strained effort to avoid using the word "shop" when the question is not inherently a shopping one.

Comment: That's why it takes 3 votes to close a question, not just one.

Comment: @user180760 regarding "more and more common" I'll spare you my detailed cynicism ... maybe if someone gains experience installing these, learning to use suitable silicone products, learning what circumstances (framing etc) cause leaks and how to avoid them ... maybe you can become good at it.  Look, there are people who fabricate shower pans by hand from rolls of lead sheet.  But I assure you THOSE people would not TOUCH your pan.  My advice in my answer stands ... LET THEM convince you that a person inexperienced with detachable flanges can be successful every time.

Comment: The whole point of buying at CostCo is to save money and have a great shopping experience. So maybe don't change horses midstream, and just accept the installation glitches as a fair exchange for the considerable value of CostCo.

Answer (score 3):

You should phone the maker of yours and ask them how the silicone and screws are designed to prevent leaking from the corner where the two flanges meet.   Their documentation and their youtube channel don't provide much confidence, but if they can convince you there is a good way to do it, go ahead.  But otherwise: yes, you should find a better shower pan.